# Native Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, docker

Recently I have read some news articles that states Microsoft is working with Docker to make docker run natively on Windows Server.

The thing I want to ask is, will this allow Windows applications to run inside docker containers, or is this just a way to run the already availble library of docker images (which runs a specific subset of a linux derivative inside them) to run on Windows without the use of a VM?

Comment: Related: [Can you run Docker natively on the new Windows 10 (Ubuntu) bash userspace?](http://serverfault.com/questions/767994/can-you-run-docker-natively-on-the-new-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-userspace/768211) on ServerFault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's about running Windows containers in Windows hosts.

Linux containers will still need to run on Linux (or within a Linux VM on a Windows host, but you can *already* do that today, with boot2docker).

[Here is a source from Microsoft](http://msopentech.com/blog/2014/10/15/docker-containers-coming-microsoft-linux-server-near/). Note the diagram.

Comment: Well wired said, that Microsoft said that they will run docker containers ;) https://twitter.com/WIRED/status/522568640227717121

Comment: @AndreasSteffan Containers share the kernel of the host. If you can show me how a Linux container can use a Windows kernel, I'm be very curious to hear about it. Now, yes, *Docker* itself will run on Windows, but it'll run Windows *containers* there. The Wired line is technically correct (but misleading; it's a Wired line), only you misunderstood it. Updated my answer with a source for you (surely that'll make the answer better anyway, so thanks for your comment).

Comment: Will try to be more clear when making fun next time. But thanks for the link to the MS blog.

Comment: @AndreasSteffan Oh, sorry, I didn't realize you were making fun of the Wired line. :( My bad!

Comment: Don't worry, its ok. ;)

Comment: Ok thanks i see. So its just a way to containerize applications that already run on windows, just with the added benefits of docker like images and online repositories for sharing images. Thats good, thanks.

Comment: Acctually there could be linux containers running in windows, it is not strict that they should share the kernel but some specific contracts need to be follow. A example is lx-zones running on Solaris, there a thin layer of states contracts enable a Solaris kernel to run linux guests containers inside solaris zones (this is how Joyent public cloud run containers on bare metal) https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/LX+Branded+Zones

Answer (score 1):

Windows Server has one feature called 
Windows Services for UNIX (SFU) or Subsystem for UNIX-based Applications (SUA)
This as a kernel extension of Windows but is minimal.

I believe this is possible if Microsoft change these "kernel extension" to be compatible to Linux most recents kernels,  to do one "think" that can run some user-mode Linux applications.

Comment: Thats a possibility, its just always emulation layers have problems. It can be useful for some simple utilities but further than that the hassle will be too much, rather just spin up a VM provider by, say, a clous provider thats natively linux and do everything on that.

Answer (score 0):

Last update for Windows Server 2016 TP3

https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome