# Docker native Windows support?

Tags: windows, docker

I have a hard time finding information about this. Somewhere I've seen news that Docker has now natively been integrated to Windows. So apparently this means they are not "Linux container" but some kind of "Windows containers"? Does anyone have more information on this?

Comment: My understanding is that the native support in Windows is included in the upcoming Windows 10 release, not in any existing one

Comment: possible duplicate of [Native Docker on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403359/native-docker-on-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have read this:
https://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/16/docker-client-for-windows-is-now-available/

As you can read there is only interface to manage docker containers inside Linux so far.

Comment: ok so native Docker CLI for windows is now available, but Docker Engine still runs in boot2docker. Thanks.

Comment: Do not forget that docker relies heavily on Linux specifics like Linux kernel namespace http://lwn.net/Articles/531114/ ,cgroups for allocating resources http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups, so you can guess there will be some work needed before having a native docker on Windows 10 (or any Windows OS)

Answer (score 3):

There has been a significant update thanks to many Docker acquisitions, such as [Unikernel](https://www.docker.com/press-release-01212016docker-acquires-unikernel-systems-extend-breadth-docker-platfrom). Now it is possible to install [beta](https://blog.docker.com/2016/03/docker-for-mac-windows-beta/) (as of April '16) of Windows program running Docker without any hassle.

> Faster and more reliable: no more VirtualBox! The Docker engine is running in an Alpine Linux distribution on top of an xhyve Virtual Machine on Mac OS X or on a Hyper-V VM on Windows, and that VM is managed by the Docker application.

---

**UPDATE** (September '17)

Full native support [available here](https://www.docker.com/docker-windows).

> An integrated, easy-to-deploy development environment for building, debugging and testing Docker apps on a Windows PC. Docker for Windows is a native Windows app deeply integrated with Hyper-V virtualization, networking and file system, making it the fastest and most reliable Docker environment for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has added containerization primitives to the Windows kernel and are helping porting Docker Engine to Windows. That means you can run native Windows containers with Docker on Windows Server 2016. It's been in tech preview for a while and is free to try. Details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/manage_docker?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

Currently (October 2016) there're a mess here. 
Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 build 1607 (Anniversary Update) support Docker containers natively. Obviously only with Windows as base images. Moreover only with Windows Server 2016 (Nano or Core).

But there's also Docker for Windows - which is the only suggested option on https://www.docker.com/products/docker#/windows. It's easily can be thought that that Docker is the one which runs natively on Windows. But it isn't! 
Docker for Windows uses a VM with Linux to host all containers. So you can't pull Windows images.

So a try to pull an image will fail with "unknown blog" error:

`C:\>docker pull microsoft/nanoserver
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from microsoft/nanoserver
5496abde368a: Retrying in 1 second
94b4ce7ac4c7: Downloading
unknown blob`

**So Docker for Windows can be used only for Linux images!**
How f... it's obvious, right?

For "real native Docker" (to run Windows container) we currently have download and install it manually as described in this manual - https://msdn.microsoft.com/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10

Comment: Docker for Windows currently supplies BOTH Linux (as per VM) and native Windows hyper-v containers. You can switch to either.

Comment: @FalcoAlexander Only beta version, not the "Docker for Windows" downloaded from docker.io

Comment: if that is the case, head to the MSDN docs and repo and ignore docker.com. Docker Inc. only supports Docker on Win2016.  I never got this DfW stuff working on my Win10.  the simple steps from MSDN Link work very fine.

Comment: yes, it works fine. but only with Windows-based containers.

Comment: Would you expect to Run Windows game on Linux? 