# Docker on Windows 10 does it work?

Tags: windows, docker, microsoft-virtualization

I need to run docker on my new Windows 10 Home laptop.
Until recently, the docker website said that it didn't work on Windows 10. It now says you need Windows 7.1 or later.
But it also says that virtualization must be enabled.

Task Manager on my machine says that it isn't enabled (says, Hyper-V support is yes though).
I see that I need Windows 10 Pro to have virtualization capability.

Before I upgrade, does anyone know that Windows 10 Pro does indeed run docker?
Does it run it without troubles?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481055/docker-native-windows-support as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26403359/native-docker-on-windows and I suspect that you will need Windows 10 Pro once Docker for Windows is out of Beta.

Answer (score 7):

First, we are talking about Windows supporting a Linux VM for supporting docker in that Linux VM.
Windows itself won't support natively docker before a Windows Server 2016 SR3+.

Second, the [Docker installation on Windows page](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/installation/windows/) says:

> Your machine must be running Windows 7.1, 8/8.1 or newer to run Docker. Windows 10 is not currently supported

Actually ([from this article](http://www.westerndevs.com/getting-docker-running-on-windows-10/)), Windows 10 is also supported, but:

> as it turns out, HyperV and VirtualBox will not run together side-by-side in 64 bit modes. And Scott’s blog post about rebooting to a hypervisorlaunchtype off mode of Windows 8.1 worked flawlessly for Windows 10

See "[Switch easily between VirtualBox and Hyper-V with a BCDEdit boot Entry in Windows 8.1](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/switcheasilybetweenvirtualboxandhypervwithabcdeditbootentryinwindows81.aspx)" (which applies here for Windows 10 as well)

[image: https://agileramblings.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/docker-windows-10.png?w=600&h=308]

Comment: Can Docker work on Windows 10 Home?

Comment: @Shimmy Possible, through VirtualBox only, not Hyper-V. See https://forums.docker.com/t/installing-docker-on-windows-10-home/11722/2 for some limitations. And I am talking about Docker Linux (running on VM in Windows). I am not talking about Docker for Windows server (https://www.docker.com/docker-windows-server), which runs only Windows image, and needs a Windows Server 2016 or more.